# How can I download files via Tor Browser?

Tags: configuration

Newb question, but when I click on links to download files nothing happens. Is there a configuration or an action that I'm not taking? Basically trying to d/l files from The PB. What am i missing? Thanks!

Comment: Tor Browser should be able to download files without issue. Do you recieve any errors? Does it work on other sites?

Answer (score 1):

The PB - a PirateBay - does **not** have *any* file on it - it has a "magnet links" for torrents, a bittorrent client must be integrated into any browser to handle them. But using torrents via Tor in a plain mode is not such a good idea - I'm almost finished my work on bringing torrents into a darknets - it only seems that you can use "privacy mode" and/or proxies specified in your torrent client: I know, I thought so myself. It is **definitely NOT** that simple! A patches must be applied to many things to make it work properly. So if you want to run torrent inside Tor - I don't recommend you to do so. If you need Tor just to cherrypick a magnet links - just copy them to a Notepad and paste later into your torrent client. But don't run torrent in plain via Tor - you can contact me in Facebook(a profile link in my profile here) and I will alert you when I'll release the patched software set.